# EF Core null semantics with grouped join

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've simplified the models and queries to aid with asking this question, which is about performance over large sets of data. In short I have a query that under-performs what it could do, and I'm trying to work out how to inform EF Core that it doesn't need to perform null-checking on the join.

I have the following EF Core models:

```cs
[Table("Item")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [Identity]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] // As such the column is marked as NOT NULL
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot perform a full-outer join on the table as the database engine doesn't support it. As such I need to group all the codes in `Item` and then use that as the source for a join back to the table for the query, as such:

```cs
var outer = from item in db.Items
            group item by item.Code into itemGroup
            select new { Code = itemGroup.Key };

var deleted = from item in db.Items
              where Deleted == true
              group item by item.Code into itemGroup
              select new { Code = itemGroup.Key, Size = itemGroup.Count() };

var fullSet = from grouping in outer
              join deleted in deleted on grouping.Code equals deleted.Code into deletedLeftJoin
              join deleted in deletedLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { Code = grouping.Code, Deleted = deleted.Size };
```

Whilst this does work, it doesn't perform well as it results in SQL *like* this:

```sql
SELECT t.Code, t1.Size as [Deleted]
FROM 
(
    SELECT Code
    FROM Items
    GROUP BY Code
) as t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Code, COUNT(*) as Size
    FROM Items
    WHERE Deleted = 1
    GROUP BY Code
) as t1
ON (t1.Code = t.Code) OR (t1.Code IS NULL AND t.Code IS NULL)
```

Is there a way to prevent the `OR (t1.Code IS NULL AND t.Code IS NULL)` in the query above. We know that the column and therefore the grouping cannot ever contain null, however the IS NULL check is introduced into the query as `Code` is a reference type.
If the OR is remove from the above statement the performance of the query is improved substantially.

I've tried using a model where `Code` is marked as a `Required` property as the result of the `GroupBy()` but this made no difference.

Comment: You have to use [UseRelationalNulls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/null-comparisons#using-relational-null-semantics)

Comment: Hi thanks for the link. Because of the warning, I'd be keen to see if there is a way to do this per-query. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't know another solution. For me this warning is about nothing. If you care about `(null) == (null)` difference, you have to keep distance from this setting.